# Read Data from RAM in python

Tags: python, windows, ram, random-access

I want to read the data from RAM (Random Access Memory) in python.
I know this is a vague question. But I am eager to know how do you do it.

I use Microsoft Windows 10 and Programming language Python

Please help and Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Modern operation systems use virtual memory via [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit). User-land processes do not have direct access to the physical memory. There is no chance for your python app to access arbitrary area of physical memory unless you use extra driver.

Comment: when you start several copies(processes) of the same executable you usually expect to get isolated executional flows of the same code and OS provides you with exactly the same concept. It is ok to do this and it is expected that all processes have theirs own copies of variables (contexts) , right? When you run independent processes then nobody expect you to ever need to read other process' memory (unless you write some kind of malware code). OS is designed to prevent you to do what you actually want to do in this particular case.

Comment: A kernel-mode component such as a driver can open and map "\Device\PhysicalMemory" via [`ZwOpenSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwopensection). It's not allowed in user mode because this section object is flagged `KernelOnlyAccess`.